# QGIS 3.10 Populate attribute table with ellipsoidal distances along lines

Tags: qgis, line, distance, ellipsoid

I have a GIS with a logistics layer that contains line features. The lines have been digitised from aerial photography and each line represents a path from A to B, following roads, rail and waterways.

**My goal is to write the real world distance along each path to a column within the attribute table.**

So far I have tried using:

[Toolbox > Vector geometry > Add geometry attributes]
[image: Add Geometry Attributes]

The results are as follows:
[image: Results]

My result of 16.5 is confusing, because the actual distance in this case is about 1650km. I followed a tutorial to do this and their results were in metres, so I guess my questions are:

1. Is my result in degrees or some other units?
2. Is there a better way to get the ellipsoidal distance along each line into the attribute table?

*(Edited to note I am using QGIS 3.10)*

Comment: Area & length calculation in QGIS cares about the layer CRS. And your layer is in EPSG 4326 - thus, your results are in degree. Try to find a CRS fitting your AOI which is based on m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under "Project Properties > General"

Set the ellipsoid to WGS84 and units to km.
[image]

Then use "Attribute Table > Field Calculator"
[image]

The **$length** function can then be used to update a distance column correctly as it respects the current project's ellipsoid and distance unit settings.